# How to edit someone's windows form(c#)?

Tags: c#

I am begineer and sorry for bad question. i downloaded someone's source code of tictactoe and opened in visual studio. I see Form.cs and Form.Designer.cs files and only way to edit game's visual is to edit Form.Designer.cs code. Is there any way to edit it like windows form? I want to manually drag buttons, labels etc...

Answer (score 1):

It is recommented to create your own winform and copy the sourcecode into it. But you have to be careful with source code of other oeople, because you don't know theur project. So create a winform app and try it